# Tamanho máximo para o nome de stored procedures, fields, etc ... no Firebird

Tags: firebird

Pesquisei em várias fontes e não encontrei resposta definitiva para esta questão.

Creio que isso seja uma questão pertinente pois, baseados nisso, podemos 
criar os nomes dos objetos de banco de dados vislumbrando estes limites.

Por exemplo, suponha que eu tenha uma `stored procedure` com o nome `SPD_MINHA_STORED_PROCEDURE_REVOLUCIONARIA_PROJETADA_PARA_SALVAR_O_MUNDO`.

Essa sequência tem 72 caracteres. Suponha que, eu crie, outra procedure 
com o nome 
`SPD_MINHA_STORED_PROCEDURE_REVOLUCIONARIA_PROJETADA_PARA_SALVAR_A_GALAXIA`.

Agora suponha que, o Firebird entenda e considere apenas os 30 primeiros 
caracteres (que no caso do nome destas *procedures*, são iguais).

Quando eu invocar estas *stored procedures*, terei problemas pois, se o 
Firebird entende e considera apenas os 30 primeiros caracteres do nome, 
como vou saber qual procedure está sendo chamada?

Quais os limites para os nomes dos objetos de banco de dados informasse os mesmos nas relações 
abaixo:

```
FireBird Versão 2.5.5
Stored Procedures -> Limite do nome = ?
Table -> Limite do nome = ?
View -> Limite do nome = ?
Trigger -> Limite do nome = ?
Exception -> Limite do nome = ?
Nome de variáveis/parâmetros de stored's -> Limite do nome = ?
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudandaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo (se tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Realmente não achei documentação oficial. O limite do identificador no Firebird 2.5 é 30 caracteres (ou 31 segundo [algumas fontes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-structure-identifiers.html)). Apesar de não ser oficial, é o que diz várias respostas em fóruns e outros sites na internet. Não importa onde o identificador é usado, então em todos os casos acima se atenha a estes limites para não ter problemas. Parece que [irão aumentar no 4.0](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/planning-board/).

Se tiver dúvida se isto está correto sugiro criar dois identificadores para o mesmo tipo de objeto dentro de DB com um tamanho maior onde a diferença entre os nomes ocorra apenas nos caracteres que superam o limite, os caracteres dentro do limite devem ser iguais, isto causaria um conflito de nomes. Vai diminuindo, o limite que não causar conflito é o limite da implementação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: bigown, já pensei em fazer isso. Na verdade, dada a falta de documentação a respeito, será a única maneira de descobrir o limite.
Pra piorar a situação, estou usando o componente SimpleDataset, e tenho duas procedures com nomes grandes. Quando dou um add em um simple dataset, ele carrega os campos do outro dataset, justamente pelo problema de limitação de campos. E olha que, neste caso, a coincidência de nome já para no décimo sexto caracter ....
Ou seja, se tiver duas sp cujos nomes sejam iguais até o 16 caracter, já tenho um problema ....
Mas valeu, vou ver o que fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Existem dois tipos de identificadores: regulares e delimitados. Eles tem regras diferentes de uso. Identificadores delimitados só estão disponíveis no dialeto 3.

Mas falando apenas sobre **limite**, o limite para ambos identificadores é 31 caracteres.

Isso está na documentação/manuais/materiais para referência. Veja o seguinte link:
http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-structure-identifiers.html